decrease height of separator in custom theorem style
I have made a definition of a separator custom theorem style in LaTeX. The separator separates the header of the theorem from the body. I would like the full line of the separator to be thinner. Alternatively, I would like the distance between the header, the rule and the body be smaller.
This is my MWE.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcommand{\separator}{\rule[.2ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\\}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headpunct={},
  postheadspace=\newline,
  postheadhook={\separator},
  mdframed={
  } 
]{question_style}

\declaretheorem[style=question_style,title={Question}]{question}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[Important question]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{question}

\end{document}


I have tried several things such as removing the \newline from postheadspace but then the rule is not on a new line. I cannot add newline to the postheadhook because then it complains "there is no line to end". If I add vspace in the separator, the spacing is not correct.

After some fidling, \newcommand{\separator}{\rule[1.2ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\vspace{-0.8ex}\\} seems to be better

\newcommand{\separator}{\rule[.8ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\\}

You seem to have answered your question in the comments, so here I'll recommend considering tcolorbox over mdframed. It has far fewer bugs and is actively maintained. Here is a possible implementation of your theorem box using tcolorbox and keytheorems (disclaimer, I wrote the latter).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keytheorems}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\separator}{\rule[1.2ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\vspace{-1ex}}

\newkeytheoremstyle{question_style}
  {
    headpunct={},
    break,
    postheadhook=\separator\par,
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    tcolorbox-no-titlebar={
      sharp corners,
      colback=white,
      left=2mm,
      right=2mm,
      top=1mm,
      bottom=1mm,
      boxrule=0.8pt,
      },
  }

\newkeytheorem{question}[style=question_style]

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[Important question]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{question}

\end{document}


